# What is an antonym for 'luddite'?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What are some single-word options for the antonym for a luddite?

Its a great word with an interesting etymology, I am just wondering if there are any similarly storied words that mean the opposite?

From Dictionary.com

> **Luddite** - noun
>
> 2. someone who is opposed or resistant to new technologies or technological change.

Comment: [Closed but possibly related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474330/catching-word-term-for-people-who-support-technology-as-a-solution-for-everythin), depending on what exactly you take to be the opposite of _luddite_.

Comment: @k1eran a "pioneer" is not the antonym of a Luddite, most of the answers in the older question are inappropriate for the OP's request.

Comment: The word *luddite* usually carries an implied criticism of the person to whom it is applied. Is the question seeking a word that also implies criticism, or a word that implies praise? In other words, is the antonym supposed to be the opposite of *luddite* only in its descriptive meaning, or both in its descriptive and in its evaluative meaning?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The antonym of 'luddite' is 'technophile'.

According to Etymologyonline:

technophile (n.)

1968, from techno- + -phile.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***TECHNOPHILE***

: a person who is enthusiastic about new technology.

***LUDDITE***

: *derogatory* 
a person opposed to increased industrialization or new technology.

Comment: I see a lot of good answers from you, well-referenced too but hardly any links. I want to say "never" but that would mean checking all your answers... Do you do that deliberately or do have some sort of difficulty with the editor toolbox?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you included the links, so that users and visitors could confirm your answer? It's a suggestion of mine, I'm not saying you must.

Comment: I'll try to, but, unfortunately, I am not a very confident user of linking and have to use only my mobile phone. I have some difficulties in full answering. Sorry.

Comment: @user307254 Put [ ] round the text you click on and ( ) round the hyperlink itself, with _no space_ in between the brackets and the parentheses. [Like this] (//meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... but without the space.

Comment: And to really drive the point home, you can also say they're an "early adopter technophile". Some people love tech and are enthusiastic and others go a step further and purchase/embrace the new technology as soon as possible.

Comment: There’s a StackExchange mobile App. It’s got a bunch of tools to add links and so if you’re not the best with markdown.

Comment: I always thought the opposite of a Luddite was someone who likes rust

Answer (score 9):

One antonym is the [**vanguard**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vanguard) (“The forefront of an action or movement”), **leading-edge** or **cutting-edge**.  Another is [**avant-garde**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant-garde), although this connotes being at the cutting edge of social change, and Luddite primarily connotes being against technological change.

Someone who embraces all the latest technology is an **early adopter**, and someone who adopts technology too early is on the **bleeding edge**.   Someone who follows the latest trends in lifestyle or fashion is **trendy**.  Someone who’s very optimistic about societal change is **utopian**, and someone who works to make things more modern is a **modernizer**.

Comment: Plus 1 for suggesting early adopter.

Answer (score 4):

An *early adopter* is about the closest you can get to a direct antonym to *luddite*.

> someone who is one of the first people to start using a new product, especially a new piece of technology
>   [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/early-adopter)

Another equivalent term for this would be *technology enthusiast*. In addition to an affinity for technology (compared to the aversion of a luddite), these people are also often seen as *influencers* or *trendsetters* if the technology that they choose to adopt becomes more popular. They follow trends in the industry and buy products based on their specifications even if it is not advertised. They will be among the first to adopt and try a new technology, even if it is expensive and there is uncertainty if it will be successful. They'll also be the first to criticise or review it. For this reason, the opinion of these people is highly valued by the tech market as the success of their products depends on the recommendations of these people.

Answer (score -1):

The first word that comes to my mind for a `reckless technology adept` who does not collaborate with factories (corporations) for meaningless job is `cyberpunk`.